# Hyperlink zoom to feature in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, hyperlink

Trying to build a hyperlink that zooms to a specific location on an arcgis online webapp.

so you're on some sort of asset management database. you're looking at the specs of a specific block in a city. you click 'show on map' or 'go to asset' and it takes you to the asset on a map on a different webpage.

Comment: Please modify your question to explain what you have already tried/what you are stuck at.  There is documentation out there on setting up hyperlinks in AGOL.  https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/link-to-items.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a web app created with web app builder you can use this documentation to open a web app created with the web app builder and define an extent.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/manage-apps/app-url-parameters.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_7D207DF919C049D68B7F9E1423962B4E

Answer (score 0):

Use Story Map Journal and add "main stage actions" to your application.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/12/18/story-map-journal-main-stage-actions/